# Question about principle of multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a quick question about principle of multiprocessing in python. For instance, if there are 35 tasks with 24 processes, how multiprocessing works? which one is right?

A. 35 out of 35 tasks is run by 24 cores.

B. 24 out of 35 tasks is run by 24 cores, at first.
   After 24 works are done, rest of 35 tasks(11) is run by 11 cores.

If B is right, how can I always use 24 cores in multiprocessing?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=24)
    test_list = [sub_1, sub_2, sub_3, sub_4, ..., sub_35]
    results = pool.map(labeling, test_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Your computer may not even have that many cores. Using multiprocessing doesn't *guarantee* that processes will be run in parallel - it simply *allows* them to be, if the computational resources exist. There's no way to answer your question precisely, because it depends what else the computer is doing at the time.

Comment: Python doesn't dictate any particular model, but creating a pool with 24 processes would do what you appear to be asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task scheduling by Python itself is FIFO, so once you've submitted all your tasks it's up to the kernel to do the scheduling between the processes in the pool. Multi-processing leaves the task of process scheduling up to the OS kernel.

So it's a bit more complicated than that. The processes might be scheduled in a lot of ways depending on what the OS decides. 
Usually OS kernels are smart about scheduling the processes to maximize CPU usage. So if you have 24 cores, and a pool of 24 processes, you can expect your CPU to be optimally utilized - but of course that will depend on what your tasks actually do.

So once you submit all your tasks to the pool:

- The first 24 tasks will be picked up by the 24 processes
- These tasks run until completion (and that depends on how the processes are scheduled by the kernel)
- As soon as a process is done with the task, a new task will be submitted to it. This will keep happening until the task submitted are all completed.

The best way to find out how efficiently your CPUs are being utilized is to monitor the CPU usage itself.